# Cannot get next song to play after onCompleteListener

Tags: java, android, path, android-mediaplayer

I have read numerous different responses on this matter but I just wanted to clarify one thing about the onCompletionListener method for MediaPlayer. I have a configuration that is currently working and playing a song after it completes the first one, but after the second one ends it will not play another song from the array. It will also not display the metadata for the new track either. My guess is that the onCompletionListener only runs once and doesn't transfer to the newly created MediaPlayer instance. More Specifically the answer I'm looking for is can the onCompleteListener run more than once? Or is it a non looping function?

Video demonstrating the issue: https://youtu.be/WXDtCktTh3M

Here is what I have for my listener block:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                if (chosenPath == null) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    songOrderCounter += 1;
                    System.out.println("SONG_ITERATOR_COUNT: " + songOrderCounter);
                    try {
                        /*handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
                        songUpdateTimeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSongTime);*/
                        Log.d("PATH_WORKING", allMusicFiles[songOrderCounter].toString());
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(allMusicFiles[songOrderCounter].toString());
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                metaRetriever();
                                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                            trackTime();
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        metaRetriever(); /* Moved inside onPrepared*/


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("NEXT_SONG_FAILED: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

The reason this is not working is because I have created a new MediaPlayer Instance in the onCompletion() function so the listener will not associate with the newly created MediaPlayer instance. Therefore it will not listen for the completion of the newly created MediaPlayer. I removed the new MediaPlayer section of code from the setOnCompleteListener() function and now there are issues with the runnable threads that are keeping track of seekbar and time progress causing it to crash when it reaches the end of the file

```
D/PATH_WORKING: /storage/emulated/0/Music/01 Control.mp3
I/System.out: NEXT_SONG_FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer, PID: 12784
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
        at com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.MainActivity$12.run(MainActivity.java:596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

And the Runnable causing the crash:

```
private Runnable moveSeekBarThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                seekBar.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos_new);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100); //Looping the thread after 0.3 second
                // seconds
            }else{}
        }
    };
```

Comment: I Figured out why the track information wasn't updating. The metaRetriever(); Metadata retriever function was not inside the onPrepared block

Comment: It is only playing one song in the allMusicFiles array. Does the onCompleteListener function only run once?

Comment: I think this is happening because the onCompletion() listener is not listening to the newly created instance of mediaPlayer. But if it has the same naming convention it should listen to it again on the next song and play another iteration of the Song Path array.